# Select sum by date distinction SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Transaction Table

```
No   Date        Amount 
1   06-07-2017   1000
2   06-07-2017   1500
3   08-07-2017   2000
4   09-07-2017   2000
5   09-07-2017   2000
6   09-07-2017   2000
```

Is it possible to achieve this result with single query ( no query loop)

```
No   Date        Total Amount
1   06-07-2017      2500
2   08-07-2017      2000
3   09-07-2017      6000
```

Comment: Yes, it is! (Hint: `GROUP BY` and `SUM()`.)

Comment: Does the transaction table actually have a column called `No`? Do you actually want a `No` in your results, but not the one from the records? (That's the only difficult part. Well, not really difficult; you'd use `ROW_NUMBER` to number your result rows. If you don't need a `No` column, then make sure you don't show any in your desired result in your request.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for `Group By`?

```
    select Trunc("Date"), -- we have to put ".." since Date is a Keyword in Oracle
           sum(Amount) as "Total Amount"
      from MyTable
  group by Trunc("Date")
  order by Trunc("Date")
```

**Edit**: it seems that `Date` field contains date and *time*, while *time* part should be *truncated* - `Trunc` - when aggregating (see the comments)

Comment: Single quotes for that column alias -  will Oracle accept that?

Comment: @jarlh: I'm sorry for the typo, `"Total Amount"` should be in double quotes for sure

Comment: Doesn't work, it doesn't summarize date and sum the amount

Comment: @Angger: what do you mean by *summarize date*? How can dates be summed up? We're summing up amounts grouping them by date

Comment: Still results like "select * from transaction" @Dmitry Bychenko

Comment: Column date's data type?

Comment: Unless I'm using DISTINCT date, but the amount still won't sums up

Comment: @Angger: so you have date and *time* and time part should be *truncated*

Answer (score 1):

For the exact results:

```
select row_number() over (order by date) as No,
       date, sum(amount) as "Total Amount"
from t
group by date
order by date;
```

Note:  In Oracle, the `date` data type can contain a time component -- and this might not be visible in the output.  If so, the aggregation doesn't do what you expect.  If this is the case, then:

```
select row_number() over (order by trunc(date)) as No,
       trunc(date) as date, sum(amount) as "Total Amount"
from t
group by trunc(date)
order by trunc(date);
```

Comment: This will not work. it would throw error `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression` since you are not using `rownum` in group by clause while using it in Select.